# Vampire film about a college guy turning into a vampire

Tags: story-identification, movie, vampire

I watched that film about 15-20 years ago.

From what I remember it seemed also to have strong comedy elements. It started with a college (or late high school?) guy who delivers something to a house. There he is seduced by a beautiful vampiress and...bitten.

He then turns into a vampire and gets a visit by an old mentor type vampire who tells him the pros and cons of being a vampire (like aging only 1 year every 10 years and that as he is not a dead living but a living dead sunlight is hurting his eyes a bit, but does not turn him to ash).

From what I then remember:

- He has a best friend who is quite well read
- He tries out his newfound powers.....also trying to hypnotize the girl he likes...but I THINK it didn't work on her....in the end he tries to get her to like him the old fashioned way
- The Vampiress who turned him gets a visit by a vampire hunter and his assistant and seemingly dies when her house burns down.
- The vampire hunters manage to track him down and after much action they corner him on a cemetery where his friend and the girl protect him.
- Suddenly the old vampire turns up as does the vampiress who everyone thought of as dead, and turns the hunter.
- The assistant flees swearing to stay as a vampire hunter to avenge his (now vampire) boss.
- The girl and the main character kiss

That is about all I remember of that film.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is [My Best Friend Is A Vampire](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Best_Friend_Is_a_Vampire). It was released in 1987.

From Wikipedia:

> Recently, Jeremy has been having some weird nightmares about a strange
>   woman trying to seduce him, and later he actually encounters that
>   woman named Nora (Cecilia Peck), who makes an obvious invitation to
>   him, while delivering groceries. His skirt-chasing friend Ralph (Evan
>   Mirand) convinces him to take up the opportunity for a first erotic
>   experience. But the encounter goes badly: First the woman bites him in
>   the neck, then two strangers burst into the house, forcing Jeremy to
>   run for his life.

All points seem to match the film.

- The main character wears sunglasses because the sunlight hurts his eyes.
- He is chased by vampire hunters to a chapel but ultimately saved by his vampire mentor and his vampire sire.
- One of the hunters is turned in to a vampire himself.